# Stored procedure isn't working with a dynamic where clause

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

I have created a stored procedure that has a few select statements and the last where the condition is inside a @command. Since I am running this in C#.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[SearchList]  
    @command varchar(2000) 
AS
BEGIN
    SELECT * 
    FROM XYZ + CONVERT(varchar(2000), @command)
END
```

I keep getting an error

> Conversion failed when converting the varchar value ' ORDER BY ID DESC' to data type int

```
DECLARE @return_value int

EXEC    @return_value = [dbo].[SearchList]
        @command = N' ORDER BY Id DESC'

SELECT  'Return Value' = @return_value
GO
```

The output returns a list which I then bind it in a grid.

Comment: This feels like an [XY Problem](http://xyproblem.info). There are a lot of considerations you should be using when using Dynamic SQL, and a really important part of that is avoiding injection. Why do you need to need to pass a dynamic `ORDER BY`?

Comment: there is a where clause along side it but just to make things simple I just wrote the order by..

Comment: Then this smells even more like an XY Problem. Seems like you should be creating a **parametrised** query in your application layer.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can't mix dynamic SQL and regular SQL.  You need to make the whole thing dynamic SQL:

```
create Procedure [dbo].[SearchList]  @command nvarchar(max) 
as begin
    declare @sql nvarchar(max);
    set @sql = N'
select *
from XYZ
' + @command;

    exec sp_executesql @sql;
end;
```

Comment: Posting this answer without any discussion at all of SQL injection issues does not seem responsible to me

Comment: Even *if* Gordon mentioned injection here, @MartinSmith , someone new the the language (as the OP appears to be) would be very hard pressed to even begin to understand how to ensure that this is safe. Considering the OP wants to fully control the `WHERE` and `ORDER BY` there's a lot of consideration needed here, and I'm relatively confident that the approach here would never be able to be properly sanitised. Honestly, the "best" scenario I could see (if a dynamic SQL solution *is* required) would be using a table type parameter, but that gets ugly fast with the `WHERE` clause requirement.

Answer (score 0):

You can try below solution

```sql
CREATE PROCEDURE SPName( @ColumnName varchar(100) ) AS
begin
SELECT * FROM XYZ
ORDER BY
  CASE WHEN @ColumnName='COl1' THEN @ColumnName 
       WHEN @ColumnName='COl2' THEN @ColumnName 
       WHEN @ColumnName='COl3' THEN @ColumnName 

END
```

Approach 2

```sql
CREATE PROCEDURE SPName( @ColumnName varchar(100)  ) AS
begin
SELECT * FROM XYZ
where 1=1 AND ( COL1= @ColumnName or isnull(@ColumnName ,'')='')
end
```

Or Use two separate variable for Where Clause and Order by and use combination of above

Comment: `CASE WHEN @ColumnName='COl1' THEN @ColumnName` won't order by the column, it'll order by what ever value is in `@ColumnName`. This means that your `ORDER BY CASE...` expression and `ORDER BY @ColumnName` are synonyms. The same applies to your latter query too. And as `@ColumnName` is a scalar value and would therefore have the same value for every row, no ordering would be applied. It would be like saying `ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)` or `ORDER BY 'Any arbitrary order'`.